# i want two array list in one method

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want the two ArrayList in one method.

```java
public CheckVisitAdapter(ArrayList<VisitDetails> visitDetails, Context  context){
    this.context = context;
    this.visitDetails=visitDetails;
}

public CheckVisitAdapter(ArrayList<Visitor> visitors, Context context){
    this.context = context;
    this.visitors=visitors;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code better and explain clairly what you want. Honestly this is really not clear at all

Comment: Can't you just change the method signature to `public CheckVisitAdapter(ArrayList<VisitDetails> visitDetails, ArrayList<Visitor> visitors, Context  
    context)` and set the three variables in only one Constructor?

Comment: just pass the 2 arrays list in the same method ..

Comment: Ok, and what is a problem? Why can't you do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Pass both ArrayList as a parameter.

```
public CheckVisitAdapter(ArrayList<VisitDetails> visitDetails,  ArrayList<Visitor> visitors, Context context){
        this.context = context;
        this.visitDetails=visitDetails;
        this.visitors=visitors;
    }
```